# Lottery card probability: matching my $k$ cards with company's $n$ cards

Tags: probability

A lottery card exchange gives out lottery cards with $32$ digits. Each digit can only have the value $0$ or $1$.

Summary of my question:

> I have bought $k$ random card numbers (requirement: this is done without replacement; all cards must have different numbers from one other).
>
> The lottery company randomly draws $n$ cards (requirement: this is done with replacement; there can be duplicate card numbers).
>
> I win if any of my $k$ cards match any of the lottery company's $n$ cards.
>
> What is the probability of my winning?

I thought the answer would be:

$P(\text{I win}) = \dfrac{k\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} \dfrac{2^{32} - (i - 1)}{2^{32}}}{2^{32}}$

But that seems to be incorrect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you explain in words why you think that formula would be correct?

Comment: The summation part of the formula calculates the probability that each of the $n$ cards would be different from the others. I then multiply this expected number of distinct $n$ cards with the number of cards I have, $k$, and divide the result by $2^{32}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easier to calculate the probability that you do not win.

In order for this to happen, each of the $n$ cards drawn by the company must come from the $2^{32}-k$ cards that you have not chosen. Each of these $n$ cards are independent.

The probability this happens for the first card is therefore: $$\frac{2^{32}-k}{2^{32}} $$

The probability this happens for all $n$ cards is therefore: $$\left( \frac{2^{32}-k}{2^{32}} \right)^n$$

And the probability you win is: $$1-\left( \frac{2^{32}-k}{2^{32}} \right)^n$$

Comment: Thank you! Is it impossible or too messy to calculate the probability that I do win without first calculating the probability that I do not win?

Comment: Too messy, and probably not possible. You would have to separately consider the cases where 1 ticket wins and the rest lose; 2 tickets win and the rest lose; etc. You also have the cases where the same ticket wins multiple times! If it did work, you  would end up with the same result as the last line - but with the brackets expanded into a big polymonial.

Comment: Wow, that would be very messy! Much better to calculate the probability that I do not win first. Thanks again!